# Resize uploaded images in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image-resizing

I have this news portal i built, and the client want a different size of the featured image.

I all ready made my first desired size and they have posted around 200+ posts all ready with that image size. Now, if i change the size it only changes on the new posts / or re upload of the current featured images(which is too much to do by hand).

My Question is, is there a way to resize the uploaded images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used it, but I think the [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin does that.

Comment: I found this on wordpress stackexchange
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/

will test the one you mentioned, while i`m at it.

Comment: That one does the trick as well and with the one you linked it can regen. only specific via media page. Cheers and thanks.